# What's the etymology behind the Great Snake Variation?

Tags: opening, terminology, english-opening

This is called the Modern Defense:

```
[FEN ""]
1.e4 g6
```

This is called the Modern Defense:

```
[FEN ""]
1.d4 g6
```

This is called the "English Opening: Great Snake Variation":

```
[FEN ""]
1.c4 g6
```

Why?

Comment: Complete guess: It's by analogy with the Dragon Variation in the Sicillian, except the "snake" is even longer, the black pawns usually ending up as h7-g6-f7-e7-d6-c5

Comment: One should be wary in all of these cases about naming the opening based on the first move, because it's quite common in all of these cases to transpose to Kings Indian.